# is it possible to apply cargo fix on the fly

Tags: rust

I am using clion to write rust code, recently I facing a problem that when I compile the project, always tell me warning that some use package never been used, so I have to use `cargo fix` command to fix the problem, I was wonder is there anyway to apply optimized import like Java or any other language on the coding fly. So that I should not pay attention to optimize the package. If I ignore the package import, there is so much warning when using cargo build, If I optimize the package, waste too much time. I am searching from internet but did not find any clue.

Comment: not still irrc, but it is already a ongoing feature request. like to run `cargo clippy --fix`too on save file.

Comment: If it's like any other IntelliJ-based product, you can tell it to run commands before run configurations like compile. It might also be possible to just make the compilation not yell about unused imports unless it is compiled in release mode.